# Error Convert NSString TO NSURL Xcode 8 Error code 256

Tags: jquery, nsstring, nsurl, xcode8-beta2

Convert NSString To NSURL

this is my code but i reciving null result

```
NSString *Mystr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in (\"USDEUR\")&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys"];




NSURL *URLOne = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[Mystr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];

NSError *error1;
NSString *strresult = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:URLOne
                                                encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                                                   error:&error1];


NSLog(@"%@", strresult);
```

here is my Error

**Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "The file “yql” couldn’t be opened." UserInfo={[NSURL=http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDEUR%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys](http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22USDEUR%22)&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys)}**

Answer (score 0):

In no particular order:

- The `stringWithContentsOfURL` method is **not** intended to be used for fetching network URLs.  You should be using the **NSURLSession** API for that.
- You can't just arbitrarily URL-encode a URL like that.  I suspect that you only want to encode the contents of the q parameter, and possibly the contents of the env parameter.  You have to encode those separately and *then* concatenate them.  If you try to encode the entire string, your URL will start with `http%3A%2F%2F`....
- That's not a good method for encoding URL query string data.  Among other things, it won't encode a bunch of special characters that are technically legal in query string but that can result in misbehavior (e.g. equals signs and ampersands).  Instead, do this:

  ```
  NSString *qParameterEncoded =
      (__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(
          kCFAllocatorDefault,
          (__bridge CFStringRef)qParameter,
          NULL,
          CFSTR(":/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;="),
          kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
  ```

  or do the equivalent with `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:` and a custom `NSCharacterSet`.